# Exact replacement for jQuery .unload() event/function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to delete a user by jQuery AJAX. My code is below

```
$(window).unload(function () {

    //delete user

    $.post('182.users.php', {userName: userName, action: 'leave'}); 
});
```

But the problem is I'm using jQuery 3.1.1 & in this version .unload() is
not present (removed)

So my code is not working.

Now I need exact replacement for this code in jQuery, not RAW JS alternative.

If you believe this is no longer possible with jQuery then please share it with RAW JS

Currently I'm trying the following after searching internet & here:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {

    $.post('182.users.php', {userName: userName, action: 'leave'});
}, true);
```

But My script still not working.

Please help .

Comment: Do proper session handling on the server instead. Or use `window.onunload=function() ...`

Comment: Tried that, but did not worked..

Comment: That is not a useful comment. Errors in console? What?

Comment: No errors in the console but it just doesn't work. I tried to use 'console.log()' & 'alert()' on different browsers, but there's nothing. I believe the event is not firing & for this the code below is not executing. & remember I want a jQuery type solution first